# Difference between pressure suits and anti-g suits

Tags: pressure, aerospace-engineering, terminology

This question might come across as a newbie one but are pressure suits and anti-g suits are two names for the same thing? Google didn't turn up differences between them specifically (if there is any), and Wikipedia has separate pages for both of them. I found an [old patent paper](https://patentimages.storage.googleapis.com/b7/0d/1b/48829c22759f49/US5007893.pdf) which says it combines both pressure suits and anti-g suits though I couldn't glean much from it. Their working and effects seemed similar but I couldn't find any confirmation whether they are different. So are they different or not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A [pressure suit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pressure_suit) is **a protective suit worn by high-altitude pilots** who may fly at altitudes where the air pressure is too low for an unprotected person to survive, even breathing pure oxygen at positive pressure. Such suits may be either full-pressure (i.e. a space suit) or partial-pressure (as used by aircrew). Partial-pressure suits work by providing mechanical counter-pressure to assist breathing at altitude.

A [g-suit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G-suit), or anti-g suit, is **a flight suit worn by aviators and astronauts who are subject to high levels of acceleration force (g)**. It is designed to prevent a black-out and g-LOC (g-induced loss of consciousness) caused by the blood pooling in the lower part of the body when under acceleration, thus depriving the brain of blood.[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pressure_suit) Black-out and g-LOC have caused a number of fatal aircraft accidents

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I read both of these definition paragraphs in their wiki pages. Putting both of them here does make it clearer that both are indeed different things. Thanks

Comment: You are welcome.